# Coordinate-free definition of arc length

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm trying to write the definition of arc length on a Riemannian manifold using fancy differential geometry language, mostly as a way to become familiarized with this language. Of course, writing this definition using just calculus is trivial.

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold, and $\alpha : I \to M$ a regular curve on it. (Think of $I$ as an *abstract* interval with a smooth structure, but no preferred coordinate.) Given a coordinate $t$ on $I$, the pullback metric $\alpha^\star g$ is represented by the $1 \times 1$ matrix whose lone entry is the squared length of the tangent vector field $v : I \to TI$ with coordinate $dt(v) = 1$. If the endpoints of $I$ have coordinate $t = a$ and $t = b$, the arc length of $\alpha$ is

$$\mathcal L(\alpha) = \int_a^b \sqrt {(\alpha^\star g) (v, v)} \, dt = \int_a^b \sqrt {g_{\alpha(t)}(d\alpha_t(v), d\alpha_t(v))} \, dt$$

I find this definition unsatisfying, because I needed to introduce $t$ and $v$ just to be able to state it, even though the associated geometric concept is independent of $t$ and $v$. Is there a coordinate-free way to state this definition?

Comment: you don't need to define a coordinate on $I$ to define the pullback metric.

Comment: @RyleeLyman: With that much I agree, of course. But everything afterwards requires using $t$ and $v$.

Comment: The problem seems to come from the fact that I can't feed the form $d\alpha$ itself as argument to $g$. I need to feed $d\alpha(v)$, and multiply times $dt$ outside of the square root, to cancel the effect of arbitrarily choosing $v$. Of course, $v$ and $dt$ are literally dual bases of $TI$ and $T^\star I$, respectively.

Comment: why not define $d\alpha$ (or $g(d\alpha)$, unclear which is the trouble) to agree with your original definition up to choosing $v$?

Comment: When you rescale $v$, both $d\alpha(v)$ and $g(d\alpha(v), d\alpha(v))$ actually change. It's the whole integrand $\sqrt {g(d\alpha(v), d(\alpha(v))} dt$ that remains the same.

Comment: More precisely, by linearity, $d\alpha(kv) = k \, d\alpha(v)$ and $g(d\alpha(kv), d\alpha(kv)) = k^2 \, g(d\alpha(v), d\alpha(v))$, but... oh, wait, I think I just realized what the problem is.

Comment: A coordinate change $w = kv$ forces us to use $ds = k^{-1} \, dt$ as well. If $k > 0$, then $\sqrt {g(d\alpha(v), d\alpha(v))} \, dt = \sqrt {g(d\alpha(w), d\alpha(w))} \, ds$. But, if $k < 0$, the integrand's sign flips!

Comment: I'm not fond of coordinates either ... A radical solution is to consider (simple) curves and their resp. arc length very abstractly (categorically!) as given, and derive relations between them. For instance: Starting from a set $\mathcal S$ (of points) let $\mathcal K$ be a collection of subsets of $\mathcal S$ and a given function $L : \mathcal K \rightarrow \mathbb R^{0+}$. Two properties:   $$ (1) \, \alpha, \beta, \gamma, \in \mathcal K : \alpha \cap \beta = \emptyset \text{ and } \alpha \cup \beta = \gamma \text{ implies } L[ \, \gamma \, ] = L[ \, \alpha \, ] + L[ \, \beta \, ],$$

Comment: $$ (2) \, \alpha, \beta, \gamma, \phi, \psi \in \mathcal K : \alpha \cap \beta = \emptyset \text{ and } \alpha \cup \beta = \gamma \text{ and } \phi \cap \psi = \emptyset \text{ and } \phi \cup \psi = \gamma \\ \text{ implies } \text{ either } (\alpha \cup \phi = \alpha \text{ and } \beta \cup \psi = \psi) \text{ or } (\alpha \cup \phi = \phi \text{ and } \beta \cup \psi = \beta).$$

Then for $\mathcal G \subset \mathcal K$ whose elements are all pairwise disjoint and whose union equals $\gamma$:

Comment: $$ L[ \, \gamma \, ] = \text{Supremum}_{\mathcal F \subset \mathcal G} \left[ \, \sum_{\phi_k in \mathcal F} L[ \, \phi_k \, ] \right].$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you reparameterize the line using a coordinate $s$. There exists a scalar field $k$ such that $dt = k \, ds$, hence we must use the vector field $w = kv$ in the calculation. Substituting in the integrand, we have

$$\sqrt {g(d\alpha(w), d\alpha(w))} \, ds = \sqrt {k^2 \, g(d\alpha(v), d\alpha(v))} \, \frac 1k \, dt = \frac {|k|} k \sqrt {g(d\alpha(v), d\alpha(v))} \, dt$$

By definition of regular parameterization, $k$ is never zero. The interval $I$ is connected, hence we have two possibilities:

1. $k > 0$ everywhere, in which case $|k|/k = 1$, and the integrand's sign stays the same.
2. $k < 0$ everywhere, in which case $|k|/k = -1$, and the integrand's sign is flipped.

Hence the arc length (as defined in the question) is not a fully coordinate-free notion. It depends on the orientation of the line induced by the parameterization.

---

An even better take at it is that the definition given in the question is slightly wrong. The integral in the question actually defines an *arc length parameterization* of the curve, if we allow the upper limit of integration to vary:

$$s = \sigma(t) = \int_a^t \sqrt {(\alpha^\star g) (v, v)} \, dt$$

However, the arc length itself is actually a Lebesgue integral over the *set* $[a,b]$:

$$\mathcal L(\alpha) = \int_{[a,b]} \sqrt {(\alpha^\star g) (v, v)} \, |dt|$$

It is not an integral of a form over a chain.